# not a single-group group error in cross join

Tags: mysql, sql, cross-join

I am trying to write an SQL query that counts the total orders and the orders that have been paid for but am getting this error `not a single-group group function`,
the table looks like this:
Orders(Ordered, amountpaid)

this is my query:

```
select count(ordered) as totalOrders,
t.paidOrders
from orders
cross join (
select count(ordered) paidOrders
from orders
where amountPaid is not null
) t
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `cross join` for this.  Just use:

```
select count(*) as totalOrders,
       count(amountPaid) as paidOrders
from orders;
```

Your version doesn't work because `paidOrders` is in the outer `select` but there is no `group by`.  Hence, unaggregated columns are not allowed.  But a single query is the better way to write this logic.

Comment: that makes sense